# Vk.Ads: загрузка изображений через POST на Python, GAE

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, изображения, google-app-engine, multipart

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не удалось решить в течение двух дней поиска по SO, примерам и документациям. Очень надеюсь, что здесь найдётся решение.

Я разрабатываю сервис автоматического создания объявлений ВК на Python и Google App Engine. Изображения для объявлений сначала загружаются на мой сервер (часть 1), а оттуда уже на сервер Вк в нужное время (части 2.1 и 2.2). Вроде как на сервере изображения хранятся байт в байт те же, что и загружались, но на всякий случай код прикладываю.

Для загрузки изображений в объявления сначала нужно [получить ссылку](https://vk.com/dev/ads.getUploadURL) (это легко, потому пропускаем), затем по этой ссылке отправить POST запрос с полем file, содержащим файл изображения ([ссылка на док](https://vk.com/dev/upload_photo_ads)). Отправление изображений я реализовал двумя способами (2.1 и 2.2), но оба возвращают `errcode: 2`, что значит `повреждённый файл`. Я считаю, что дело в структуре самих запросов, однако не упускаю возможности проблемы в загрузке/хранения изображений на моём сервере или в специфической работе Vk.Ads API. За ответы и советы буду весьма благодарен.

### 1. Загрузка фото на свой сервер

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

# для хранения изображения на сервере
class Photo(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    img = ndb.BlobProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def get(name):
        retval = Photo.query(Photo.name == name).get()
        return retval

    @staticmethod
    def create(name, blob):
        retval = Photo()
        retval.name = name
        retval.img = blob
        return retval

class PhotosPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # основное содержимое страницы:
        html = '''<form action="/photos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="flimg"/>
            <input value="new_pic" name="flname"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/> </form>'''

    def post(self):
        n = str(self.request.get('flname'))
        f = self.request.get('flimg')
        p = Photo.get(n)
        if p:
            p.img = f
        else:
            p = Photo.create(n, f)
        p.put()
```

### 2.1. Отправка фото, способ #1, библиотеки [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch) и [poster](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster):

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

name = 'file'
content = ... # бинарник файла
where = ... # полученная ссылка

options = {
    'file': MultipartParam(
        name=name,
        value=content,
        filename=name,
        filetype='image/png',
        filesize=len(content))
}

data, headers = multipart_encode(options)
pocket = "".join(data)

result = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=where,
    payload=pocket,
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    headers=headers)
```

### 2.2. Отправка фото, способ #2, библиотека requests:

```
import requests

name = 'file'
content = ... # бинарник файла
where = ... # полученная ссылка

# пробовал и без этого словаря; всегда ли он нужен?
data = {
    'fileName': name,
    'fileSize': len(content),
    'description': 'undefined',
}

result = requests.post(where, files={name: StringIO(content)}, data=data)
```

Также, для второго способа мне удалось получить содержимое отправляемого сообщения:

```
POST
https://pu.vk.com/c.../upload.php?act=ads_add&mid=...&size=m&rdsn=1&hash_time=...&hash=...&rhash=...&api=1

Content-Length: 15946
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f

--b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
undefined

--b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileSize"
15518

--b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"
file

--b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file" 
< File binary content >

--b4b260eace4e4a7082a99753b74cf51f--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось тривиальным, но не очевидным. В результате множества экспериментов и исследования содержаний HTTP-запросов я нашёл единственное отличие между работающим и неработающим запросами. Разница всего лишь в 4-х байтах: название файла *ОБЯЗАНО* содержать расширение. Вк АПИ игнорирует `Content-Type: image/png` и вполне успешно обрабатывает запрос без него, если указать расширение (`.png` или иное) в названии файла `filename`.

В общем, такой код не работает:

```
requests.post(upload_url, files={
    'file': BytesIO('<binary file content>')
})
```

А этот обрабатывается успешно:

```
requests.post(upload_url, files={
    'file': ('file.png', BytesIO('<binary file content>'), 'image/png')
})
```

Как и этот простой вариант, который недоступен в GAE:

```
requests.post(upload_url, files={
    'file': open('/path/to/image.png', 'rb')
})
```

---

Оба `StringIO` и `StringIO` одинаково подходят для этой задачи. Как уже сказал, `Content-Type` не имеет значения, он может быть просто `multipart/form-data`.